# Restricting Source IP with Forward in iptables on CentOS 7 not working

Tags: iptables, nat, centos7

I have a CentOS 7 machine with a single interface setup with NAT. 
I have a Windows 8.1 machine with a single interface as a NAT client. 
Both machines are on the same IP network

The following are the relevant iptables entries

Config 1 (working)

```
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Config 2 (working)

```
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A FORWARD -s 0.0.0.0/0 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Config 3 - desired config (not working)

```
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A FORWARD -s x.x.x.x/32 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Config 1 and 2 works. And `whatismyipaddress.com` shows the address of the NAT machine from a browser on the Win8.1 machine. So I know that NAT is working and that gateway, etc is setup correctly on the Win8.1 machine.

But when I try to restrict the source IP as per config 3, I lose internet on the Win8.1 machine. And, yes I'm certain the source IP is correct.

Any ideas? Additional info needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in case 3 your FORWARD policy is DROP then you're not allowing to forward the returning flow back to the client machine. I'd say add a `-A FORWARD -d x.x.x.x/32 -j ACCEPT` . I can't be sure without seing all of your rules.

And by the way it's not a good idea to use only one interface but you must know it already.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks for that. All machines only have 1 interface and I can't change that. I did have a DROP at the end of the FORWARD chain. I actually added the following, as I only wanted to allow/forward traffic from inside the network, not outside. 
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
It works, but any issues/problems you can see with that?

Comment: This last addition will permit flows like FTP or SIP to work if you load the corresponding module helpers, as well as for example allow ICMP errors back to your "client" and it's almost always expected to be present. By the way there's an updated (and more complex) way instead of using "--state ESTABLISHED, RELATED -j ACCEPT", which is already deprecated (you even get one line of warning in dmesg kernel messages), but it's more complex. Look there: https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/secure-use-of-helpers/

Comment: My comment was about the RELATED part. The ESTABLISHED part is mostly there to be a shortcut to all your rules (for better efficiency) once a flow (be it tcp or udp or whatever) is known by conntrack. it's not needed in the -t nat part because the rules are already used only once for every (new) flow. If you had to specifically blacklist some IP, you should use a DROP *before* this ETABLISHED rule

Answer (score 0):

```
-A FORWARD -s x.x.x.x/32 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

It means that `x.x.x.x` IP address will be allowed to forward from internet `eth0`.

Change `eth0` to the interface witch is connected to your local network. The forward table is applied before the postrouting table.